# IE9 WebBrowser control does not render animations like in IE9

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer-9, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to load some html that is animated using jQuery UI into a WebBrowser control that is hosted in a WPF app.  The html is rendered very smoothly in IE9 but is kind of shaky using the WebBrowser control (see the html below)

I enabled the following IE features both under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/... AND HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Wow6432Node/SOFTWARE/...

```
FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION (using the value 9999)
FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx

Still even with those features enabled I still get the content to render slowly.  I also tried in WPF 4.5 to see if the "new" airspace could help but it didn't

Does anyone have an idea on what could be causing that or what I could do to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Pascal

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
div
{

width:960px;
height:360px;
background:blue;
color: white;
} 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slide">
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert(navigator.appVersion); // it is running in IE9 mode
            var options = { to: { right: "0"} };
            $("#slide").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question has also been asked on the WPF forum
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/614fa2e7-0d67-45c2-aeca-03b836ff2277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft (WPF team) has acknowledged the problem and has decided to not fix this issue.

See the Microsoft connect ticket here.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736253/ie9-webbrowser-control-does-not-render-animations-like-in-ie9

Also please note that I've had the same issue in a win form application.

Comment: The link is behind a login-wall; then once I finally logged in, it's a page not found. <sigh>